# Video HTML tag can't seek or jump to a specific part of the video

Tags: javascript, laravel, html5-video

I'm using JS to play the video in my page but I can't jump to specific part of the video using JS or even manually doing it.
[image]

Here's my code in blade.php

***blade.php***

```
    <video width="100%" src="{{ 'videos/stream.mp4#?t=150'}}" autoplay id="streamvideo" controls></video>
    //providing t=150 is not working too.
    <div class="play-button-overlay" id="playButton">
      <i class="fas fa-play"></i>
    </div>
```

***JS*** Using this to play and disable the user from pausing the video.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var video = document.getElementById("streamvideo");
    var playButton = document.getElementById("playButton");

    playButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      video.play();
      clssplayButton.remove();
    });

    video.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if(video.paused){
        video.play();
        clssplayButton.remove();
      }
    });
};
```

***CSS***

```
#streamvideo::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
    display: none !important;
}

#streamvideo::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button {
    display: inline-block !important;
}
```

Using JS, I also tried setting the current time but it still didn't work!

```
video.currentTime = 120;
```

Is there any way I can achieve it?

Comment: Does it work if after `var video = document.getElementById("streamvideo");` you then add new next line of code like: `video.src="videos/stream.mp4#?t=150";` and `video.load(); video.play();` ...Now does it allow seeking during playback?